# Change default name for OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE

Tags: jpa, jakarta-ee, openjpa

I'm using Sequence Generation Type. I would like to use another name for sequence generation table. OPENJPA_SEQUENCE_TABLE. How can I override the default name? I could not find a property that I can set in the persistence.xml file.

Comment: Define your annotations/XML that makes use of whatever this is. Is it strategy = TABLE ? or SEQUENCE? or what?

Comment: If this is a TABLE strategy then you can define such things with `@TableGenerator`, but unless you define what config you have got its impossible to be precise

Comment: I'm using Sequence Generation Type

Comment: If the RDBMS supports SEQUENCEs then it will NOT be using any TABLE anywhere to support that. If the RDBMS doesnt support SEQUENCEs and you specify SEQUENCE then it should throw an exception. So provide details (in your question) of what RDBMS it is, post the class, and the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i just assume that you use annotated entity classes. For this you can define the name of the sequence generator with the **@SequenceGenerator** like that:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "YOUR_TABLE")
@SequenceGenerator(initialValue = 1,
        allocationSize = 1,
        name = "YOUR_SQUENCE_NAME",
        sequenceName = "YOUR_SQUENCE_NAME")
public class YourTable implements java.io.Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "YOUR_SQUENCE_NAME")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Integer id;
}
```

Comment: but that isnt a "sequence table". It's a Sequence, a datastore sequence.

Comment: Well i just want to give a hint, becuase it is not totally clear how his JPA is done.

Comment: I'm using Sequence Generation Type